# Fail2ban regex not working

Tags: fail2ban

I would like to block any get request to /.git, /wp-login,/remote/login/,   so i have created the following filter which also includes other requests.

```
 badagents = 360Spider|ZmEu|Auto Spider 1.0|zgrab/[0-9]*\.[0-9a-zA-Z]*|Wget\(.*\)|MauiBot.*|AspiegelBot.*|SemrushBot.*|PHP/.*

failregex = ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD).*HTTP.*(?:%(badagents)s)"$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD) /+wp-login\.php.*$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD) /.git/HEAD.*$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"GET /.git/.*$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD) /wp-login/.*$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD) /.git/objects/.*$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD) //.git/objects/.*$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD) /remote/login/.*$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD) /wp/wp-includes/.*$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"GET /wp/wp-includes/.*$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"GET /wp/wp-login.php/.*$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"GET /test/wp-includes/.*$
        ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"GET /config/getuser/.*$
```

I have also attached this to my jail.local with

```
[one-time-ban]
enabled     =true
port        =http,https
logpath     = /var/log/nginx/access.log
              /var/log/nginx/prod_test.log
filter      =one-time-ban
bantime     = 300
maxretry    = 1
findtime     = 10
```

I have tested this by trying to access /.git on the url for more than 10 times but am still not getting banned. Why is this failing. I believe the issue to be at the failregex what do i need to add extra inorder for fail2ban to work?

A sample log looks like this

```
3.17.11.219 - - [05/Oct/2021:12:33:15 +0000] "GET //.git/objects/a5/920b6c86cc2d972bde9578c0a5d848dff67354 HTTP/1.1" 301 178 "-" "curl/7.61.1"
```

Comment: First create a sample log file that includes the entries you want to trigger a ban, then use the `fail2ban-regex` command to test your reg-exs. Without a sample of the logs to compare to what you have here it's hard to help.

Comment: I have included a sample log

Answer (score 0):

Your regex's (really "vulnerable" by the way) are starting with `^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -`, what means: find an IP address (or a hostname) after someting matching colon, at least 1 digit and space.
But your line is starting with IP.

So your regex's don't match your log-format at all.

Correct (and fewer "vulnerable") failregex would be something like this:

```regex
^<ADDR> \S+ \S+ (?:\[\] )?"[A-Z]+ /\S*(?<=/)(?:\.git|wp-login|remote/login)\b[^"]*"\s+
```

but better would be to forbid them via web-server (response with 403), and then find every errored request with something like:

```regex
^<ADDR> \S+ \S+ (?:\[\] )?"[A-Z]+ /[^"]*"\s+(?!401)[45]\d\d
```